# How Can I handle subprocess when a process is killed by lack of memory?

Tags: pandas, memory, subprocess, kill, kill-process

I'm trying to handle an error when a subprocess doesn't run because of a lack of memory. However, no exception is working in this case. What should I use?

```
ribodetector = [
    "ribodetector_cpu",
    "-t",
    str(threads),
    "-l",
    read_lenght,
    "-e",
    "rrna",
    "--chunk_size",
    "256",
]

# Determine which input FASTQ files to use based on file existence
if os.path.isfile(sra_filtered):
    ribodetector.extend(["-i", sra_filtered, "-o", sra_ribodetector_filtered])

elif os.path.isfile(sra_filtered_1):
    ribodetector.extend(
        [
            "-i",
            sra_filtered_1,
            sra_filtered_2,
            "-o",
            sra_ribodetector_filtered_1,
            sra_ribodetector_filtered_2,
        ]
    )

command = " ".join(ribodetector)
print(f"The command used was: {command}")

try:
    subprocess.run(ribodetector, check=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    if os.path.isfile(sra_filtered):
        os.rename(sra_filtered, sra_ribodetector_filtered)
    else:
        os.rename(sra_filtered_1, sra_ribodetector_filtered_1)
        os.rename(sra_filtered_2, sra_ribodetector_filtered_2)
```

I'm getting this message and then stop running:

```
The command used was: ribodetector_cpu -t 40 -l 101 -e rrna --chunk_size 256 -i /home/apis/vinicius_apis/SRR5117442/SRR5117442_1_filtered.fastq /home/apis/vinicius_apis/SRR5117442/SRR5117442_2_filtered.fastq -o /home/apis/vinicius_apis/SRR5117442/SRR5117442_ribodetector_1.fastq /home/apis/vinicius_apis/SRR5117442/SRR5117442_ribodetector_2.fastq
/usr/bin/bash: line 2: 258719 Killed
```

Comment: If you can't handle it, the SIGKILL is going to your Python process, not the subcommand; if it were going to the child you'd get the CalledProcessError that you expect. Notice how it's _bash_ being told that it has a child that was killed, not Python. SIGKILL, by design, can't be handled or ignored; if it's delivered to your Python process, there's nothing you can do except immediately die.

Comment: In at least some Linux kernel versions, killing a parent responsible for starting lots of memory-hungry children is intended/designed/correct behavior for the OOM killer, so this shouldn't be a surprise.

Comment: For some relevant background, see [Is there a way to configure the Linux OOM killer to kill the parent instead of the child?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631539) -- even though that's the opposite of the behavior you want, the answer describes the reasoning behind how this has changed over time, and points to some of the knobs for tweaking.